# How to fix Shimano E7000 Error 010?

Tags: shimano, repair, electric-bike

Can anyone guide me to clear the E010 error code on a Shimano E7000? I tried all the steps according to the manual but can't resolve them.

Comment: The [FAQ](https://www.shimano-steps.com/e-bikes/north-america/en/faq/troubleshooting---errors-) says "If no improvement, contact place of purchase."  Have you tried that?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43858/shimano-steps-ebike-e010-and-e012-errors-diy-fix-possible